Different Formulations of Differentials as Generating Transformations: $e^{t A}f(x) = h(x,t); A=\frac{\partial_x}{g'(x)} \& h(x,t)=f(g^{-1}(g(x)+t))$
For context and introduction please see:
Perspective on Differentials Generating Transformations of Functions - with Fourier Transformations $e^{a\partial_x} f(x) = f(x+a)$
Here I used Fourier transformations (instead of the classical series argument) to show that
$\exp{(a\partial_x)}\,f(x) = f(x+a) \iff \exp{(i ak)} \,\mathcal{F}(f(x))(k) = \mathcal{F}(f(x+a))(k)$.
From this one can substitution to arrive at
$e^{\frac{t}{g'(x)}\frac{d}{dx}}f(x) = f(G_t(x))$ with $G_t(x) = g^{-1}(g(x)+t)) \quad \quad \mathbf{(1)}$
The user LL 3.14 presented another perspective, that is seemingly more known to arrive at another general form of this transformation by exponentiation.
It utilizes differential equations instead of power series:
Let's define the solution to $\partial_t h = A h$ with $h(0) = f$ at time $t$ to be given by
$h(t) := e^{t A}f \quad \quad \mathbf{(2)}$

I now want to show that both approaches lead to the same results.

I want to transform $f \mapsto f \circ G$ via the exponent given in $(1)$, they give this solution by $h(x,t)$.
Leading me to $h(x,t)= f(G_t(x)) \quad \quad \mathbf{(3)}$.
I will know try to show that this form of $h$ solves the characteristic equations:

$\partial_t h = \partial_t f(G_t(x)) = f'(G_t(x)) \partial_t G_t(x) =  \frac{f'(G_t(x))}{g'(G_t(x))}$

$A h = \frac{1}{g'(x)}\frac{d}{dx} h(x,t) = \frac{1}{g'(x)} f'(G_t(x)) \frac{g'(x)}{g'(G_t(x))} = \frac{f'(G_t(x))}{g'(G_t(x))}$

$h(t=0) = f(G_0(x))$ with $G_0(x) = g^{-1}(g(x))) = x$



So they are the same.

I used $f'(u)$ to refer to the total derivative in dependency of one parameter $u$.
The differentiation for $t,x$ is analogous, as it depends only linearly in $t$ but from $g(x)$ the second calculation includes an additional $g'(x)$ to the $\frac{1}{g'(G_t)}$ factor.
The given variant relys on $g$ being an invertible and differentiable function (as almost all differentiable functions are localy invertible, this is enough for my purpose). That $g \in C^1$ has to be assumed to make sense of $\frac{d}{dg}$, which is the core idea leading me to this observations. The case that $g$ is not invertible in an enviroment arount $0$, $g=\, const.$, can easily be dealt with as a special case.

Now I have convinced myself that both formulations are equivalent, but are you, dear reader, satisfied with this 'proof'?
What am I missing?

I have a few question left:

Is my form of $h(x,t) = f(G_t(x))$ the only possible choice (for $A$ depending on differential operators and invertible functions)

It should be, as the solution to the differential equation should be unique, as well as the description described by $g$ and $A$!?
*What properties should the operator $A$ has?
It doesn't need to be hermitian or bounded as can be seen by the example, the defining differential equation is linear...
I hope the used function spaces are clear from their use, just assume what is necessary. If there is something special about these assumptions you can note them.
Thank you!

Can you please make this question neater and more rigorous?

Please try to use compact notation as in this paper https://dx.doi.org/10.1088/1751-8121/aa6f32.

Thanks for the reference. Which notational chance do you wish to see, I'm not sure what I should apply  where? Where do you see the biggest lack in rigour? What shall I improve?

I gave it a try, let  me know what should be improved more!

@MathArt, any advice or idea if this is true?

Yes, it is better. I might be further improved with different sizes of brackets for multilayer expressions.
